# Nokogiri XML parsing order of results

Tags: xml, parsing, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri to parse XML however I am unsure how to put it in order(alphabetical) once it has been parsed.

Any help would be great.

Comment: What do you have so far? How are you storing what you get out of Nokogiri?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have parsed the data out of your XML, you should have it in some sort of collection, most likely an array of objects or hashes.

To sort it in any order, either alphabetical or numeric, you'll probably want to use `sort_by` to compare your key field/data.

Without more detail in the question it's impossible to provide more detail in an answer.